# How can I deploy an interactive heatmap by shinyheatmaply

Tags: r, shiny, heatmaply

I am trying to deploy an interactive heatmap as a shiny app but not simply an interactive heatmap rather a fancy heatmap by shinyheatmaply but when I am running deployapp nothing happens

This is my ui

```
library(shiny)
library(heatmaply)
library(shinyHeatmaply)
data(mtcars)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Interactive heatmap"),
    fluidRow(plotlyOutput("heatmap"))
))
```

And this is my server

```
library(shiny)
library(heatmaply)
library(shinyHeatmaply)
data(mtcars)
shinyServer(function(input,output) {
    output$heatmap <- if(interactive()){
data(mtcars)
launch_heatmaply(mtcars)
}

    })
```

By running

```
rsconnect::deployApp("/Users/temporal.UOS-12599/Desktop/New folder")
```

says

```
DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 977528...DONE
Deploying bundle: 2147989 for application: 977528 ...
Waiting for task: 621761993
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 2264908
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 2264908
  deploying: Starting instances
  rollforward: Activating new instances
  terminating: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to https://fi1d18.shinyapps.io/new_folder/
```

But nothing happens at the end

EDITED

This is data I which to show in deployed app

```
> head(sample_013)
       Driver snv_t_013 snv_o_013 indel_t_013 indel_o_013 Deleted_ot_013 Deleted_o_013
ABCB1       1         0         1           0           0              0             0
ACVR1B      1         0         0           0           0              0             0
ACVR2A      1         0         0           0           0              0             0
APC         1         1         1           0           0              0             0
ARID1A      1         0         0           1           1              1             0
ARID1B      1         1         1           1           1              1             1
```

Any help please?

Comment: `launch_heatmaply` is a wrapper function using `?runGadget` (similar to `runApp`). Accordingly it creates a shiny app and runs it in one go. If you want to host the app in a different way you can get the server/ui code [here](https://github.com/yonicd/shinyHeatmaply/blob/master/R/heatmaplyGadget.R).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I deployed app by ui and server but it shows iris, cars, etc. How I can deploy that with my own data?I mean by launching the deployed app, my own data being shown instead of mtcars

Comment: Please see my example below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to pass your data to `obj`. Here is an example based on the heatmaplyGadget [code](https://github.com/yonicd/shinyHeatmaply/blob/master/R/heatmaplyGadget.R):

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(DT)
library(heatmaply)
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)

sample_013 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                         NANA = c("ABCB1", "ACVR1B", "ACVR2A", "APC", "ARID1A", "ARID1B"),
                         NADriver = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                         NAsnv_t_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                         NAsnv_o_013 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                         NAindel_t_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                         NAindel_o_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                         NADeleted_ot_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                         NADeleted_o_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))

plotHeight <- 800
obj <- list(sample_013 = sample_013, iris = iris)

if (!"list" %in% class(obj)) 
  obj = list(obj)
if (is.null(names(obj))) 
  names(obj) = paste0("data", seq(1, length(obj)))

#UI----
ui <- shiny::shinyUI(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::sidebarLayout(
      shiny::sidebarPanel(
        htmltools::h4('Data'),
        shiny::uiOutput('data'),
        shiny::checkboxInput('showSample','Subset Data'),
        shiny::conditionalPanel('input.showSample',shiny::uiOutput('sample')),
        # br(),
        htmltools::hr(),htmltools::h4('Data Preprocessing'),
        shiny::column(width=4,shiny::selectizeInput('transpose','Transpose',choices = c('No'=FALSE,'Yes'=TRUE),selected = FALSE)),
        shiny::column(width=4,shiny::selectizeInput("transform_fun", "Transform", c(Identity=".",Sqrt='sqrt',log='log',Scale='scale',Normalize='normalize',Percentize='percentize',"Missing values"='is.na10', Correlation='cor'),selected = '.')),
        shiny::uiOutput('annoVars'),

        htmltools::br(),htmltools::hr(),htmltools::h4('Row dendrogram'),
        shiny::column(width=6,shiny::selectizeInput("distFun_row", "Distance method", c(Euclidean="euclidean",Maximum='maximum',Manhattan='manhattan',Canberra='canberra',Binary='binary',Minkowski='minkowski'),selected = 'euclidean')),
        shiny::column(width=6,shiny::selectizeInput("hclustFun_row", "Clustering linkage", c(Complete= "complete",Single= "single",Average= "average",Mcquitty= "mcquitty",Median= "median",Centroid= "centroid",Ward.D= "ward.D",Ward.D2= "ward.D2"),selected = 'complete')),
        shiny::column(width=12,shiny::sliderInput("r", "Number of Clusters", min = 1, max = 15, value = 2)),    
        #column(width=4,numericInput("r", "Number of Clusters", min = 1, max = 20, value = 2, step = 1)),   

        htmltools::br(),htmltools::hr(),htmltools::h4('Column dendrogram'),
        shiny::column(width=6,shiny::selectizeInput("distFun_col", "Distance method", c(Euclidean="euclidean",Maximum='maximum',Manhattan='manhattan',Canberra='canberra',Binary='binary',Minkowski='minkowski'),selected = 'euclidean')),
        shiny::column(width=6,shiny::selectizeInput("hclustFun_col", "Clustering linkage", c(Complete= "complete",Single= "single",Average= "average",Mcquitty= "mcquitty",Median= "median",Centroid= "centroid",Ward.D= "ward.D",Ward.D2= "ward.D2"),selected = 'complete')),
        shiny::column(width=12,shiny::sliderInput("c", "Number of Clusters", min = 1, max = 15, value = 2)),
        #column(width=4,numericInput("c", "Number of Clusters", min = 1, max = 20, value = 2, step = 1)),    

        htmltools::br(),htmltools::hr(),  htmltools::h4('Additional Parameters'),

        shiny::column(3,shiny::checkboxInput('showColor','Color')),
        shiny::column(3,shiny::checkboxInput('showMargin','Layout')),
        shiny::column(3,shiny::checkboxInput('showDendo','Dendrogram')),
        htmltools::hr(),
        shiny::conditionalPanel('input.showColor==1',
                                htmltools::hr(),
                                htmltools::h4('Color Manipulation'),
                                shiny::uiOutput('colUI'),
                                shiny::sliderInput("ncol", "Set Number of Colors", min = 1, max = 256, value = 256),
                                shiny::checkboxInput('colRngAuto','Auto Color Range',value = T),
                                shiny::conditionalPanel('!input.colRngAuto',shiny::uiOutput('colRng'))
        ),

        shiny::conditionalPanel('input.showDendo==1',
                                htmltools::hr(),
                                htmltools::h4('Dendrogram Manipulation'),
                                shiny::selectInput('dendrogram','Dendrogram Type',choices = c("both", "row", "column", "none"),selected = 'both'),
                                shiny::selectizeInput("seriation", "Seriation", c(OLO="OLO",GW="GW",Mean="mean",None="none"),selected = 'OLO'),
                                shiny::sliderInput('branches_lwd','Dendrogram Branch Width',value = 0.6,min=0,max=5,step = 0.1)
        ),             

        shiny::conditionalPanel('input.showMargin==1',
                                htmltools::hr(),
                                htmltools::h4('Widget Layout'),
                                shiny::column(4,shiny::textInput('main','Title','')),
                                shiny::column(4,shiny::textInput('xlab','X Title','')),
                                shiny::column(4,shiny::textInput('ylab','Y Title','')),
                                shiny::sliderInput('row_text_angle','Row Text Angle',value = 0,min=0,max=180),
                                shiny::sliderInput('column_text_angle','Column Text Angle',value = 45,min=0,max=180),
                                shiny::sliderInput("l", "Set Margin Width", min = 0, max = 200, value = 130),
                                shiny::sliderInput("b", "Set Margin Height", min = 0, max = 200, value = 40)
        )
      ),

      shiny::mainPanel(
        shiny::tabsetPanel(
          shiny::tabPanel("Heatmaply",
                          htmltools::tags$a(id = 'downloadData', class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link",'mybutton'), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, shiny::icon("clone"), 'Download Heatmap as HTML'),
                          htmltools::tags$head(htmltools::tags$style(".mybutton{color:white;background-color:blue;} .skin-black .sidebar .mybutton{color: green;}") ),
                          plotly::plotlyOutput("heatout",height=paste0(plotHeight,'px'))
          ),
          shiny::tabPanel("Data",
                          DT::dataTableOutput('tables')
          )
        ) 
      )
    )
  )
)
#Server---- 

server <- function(input, output, session) {    

  output$data=shiny::renderUI({
    d<-names(obj)
    selData=d[1]
    shiny::selectInput("data","Select Data",d,selected = selData)
  })

  data.sel=shiny::eventReactive(input$data,{
    as.data.frame(obj[[input$data]])
  })  

  shiny::observeEvent(data.sel(),{
    output$annoVars<-shiny::renderUI({
      data.in=data.sel()
      NM=NULL

      if(any(sapply(data.in,class)=='factor')){
        NM=names(data.in)[which(sapply(data.in,class)=='factor')]  
      } 
      shiny::column(width=4,
                    shiny::selectizeInput('annoVar','Annotation',choices = names(data.in),selected=NM,multiple=T,options = list(placeholder = 'select columns',plugins = list("remove_button")))
      )
    })

    #Sampling UI ----  
    output$sample<-shiny::renderUI({
      list(
        shiny::column(4,shiny::textInput(inputId = 'setSeed',label = 'Seed',value = sample(1:10000,1))),
        shiny::column(4,shiny::numericInput(inputId = 'selRows',label = 'Number of Rows',min=1,max=pmin(500,nrow(data.sel())),value = pmin(500,nrow(data.sel())))),
        shiny::column(4,shiny::selectizeInput('selCols','Columns Subset',choices = names(data.sel()),multiple=T))
      )
    })
  })

  output$colUI<-shiny::renderUI({
    colSel='Vidiris'
    if(input$transform_fun=='cor') colSel='RdBu'
    if(input$transform_fun=='is.na10') colSel='grey.colors'

    shiny::selectizeInput(inputId ="pal", label ="Select Color Palette",
                          choices = c('Vidiris (Sequential)'="viridis",
                                      'Magma (Sequential)'="magma",
                                      'Plasma (Sequential)'="plasma",
                                      'Inferno (Sequential)'="inferno",
                                      'Magma (Sequential)'="magma",
                                      'Magma (Sequential)'="magma",

                                      'RdBu (Diverging)'="RdBu",
                                      'RdYlBu (Diverging)'="RdYlBu",
                                      'RdYlGn (Diverging)'="RdYlGn",
                                      'BrBG (Diverging)'="BrBG",
                                      'Spectral (Diverging)'="Spectral",

                                      'BuGn (Sequential)'='BuGn',
                                      'PuBuGn (Sequential)'='PuBuGn',
                                      'YlOrRd (Sequential)'='YlOrRd',
                                      'Heat (Sequential)'='heat.colors',
                                      'Grey (Sequential)'='grey.colors'),
                          selected=colSel)
  })

  shiny::observeEvent({data.sel()},{
    output$colRng=shiny::renderUI({

      rng=range(data.sel(),na.rm = TRUE)

      n_data = nrow(data.sel())

      min_min_range = ifelse(input$transform_fun=='cor',-1,-Inf)
      min_max_range = ifelse(input$transform_fun=='cor',1,rng[1])
      min_value = ifelse(input$transform_fun=='cor',-1,rng[1])

      max_min_range = ifelse(input$transform_fun=='cor',-1,rng[2])
      max_max_range = ifelse(input$transform_fun=='cor',1,Inf)
      max_value = ifelse(input$transform_fun=='cor',1,rng[2])

      a_good_step = 0.1 # (max_range-min_range) / n_data

      list(
        shiny::numericInput("colorRng_min", "Set Color Range (min)", value = min_value, min = min_min_range, max = min_max_range, step = a_good_step),
        shiny::numericInput("colorRng_max", "Set Color Range (max)", value = max_value, min = max_min_range, max = max_max_range, step = a_good_step)
      )

    })  
  })


  interactiveHeatmap<- shiny::reactive({
    data.in=data.sel()
    if(input$showSample){
      if(!is.null(input$selRows)){
        set.seed(input$setSeed)
        if((input$selRows >= 2) & (input$selRows < nrow(data.in))){
          # if input$selRows == nrow(data.in) then we should not do anything (this save refreshing when clicking the subset button)
          if(length(input$selCols)<=1) data.in=data.in[sample(1:nrow(data.in),pmin(500,input$selRows)),]
          if(length(input$selCols)>1) data.in=data.in[sample(1:nrow(data.in),pmin(500,input$selRows)),input$selCols]
        }
      }
    }

    if(length(input$annoVar)>0){
      if(all(input$annoVar%in%names(data.in))) 
        data.in <- data.in%>%mutate_at(funs(factor),.vars=vars(input$annoVar))
    } 

    ss_num =  sapply(data.in, is.numeric) # in order to only transform the numeric values

    if(input$transpose) data.in=t(data.in)
    if(input$transform_fun!='.'){
      if(input$transform_fun=='is.na10'){
        shiny::updateCheckboxInput(session = session,inputId = 'showColor',value = T)
        data.in[, ss_num]=is.na10(data.in[, ss_num])
      } 
      if(input$transform_fun=='cor'){
        shiny::updateCheckboxInput(session = session,inputId = 'showColor',value = T)
        shiny::updateCheckboxInput(session = session,inputId = 'colRngAuto',value = F)
        data.in=stats::cor(data.in[, ss_num],use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
      }
      if(input$transform_fun=='log') data.in[, ss_num]= apply(data.in[, ss_num],2,log)
      if(input$transform_fun=='sqrt') data.in[, ss_num]= apply(data.in[, ss_num],2,sqrt) 
      if(input$transform_fun=='normalize') data.in=heatmaply::normalize(data.in)
      if(input$transform_fun=='scale') data.in[, ss_num] = scale(data.in[, ss_num])
      if(input$transform_fun=='percentize') data.in=heatmaply::percentize(data.in)
    } 


    #if(!is.null(input$tables_true_search_columns)) 
    #  data.in=data.in[activeRows(input$tables_true_search_columns,data.in),]
    if(input$colRngAuto){
      ColLimits=NULL 
    }else{
      ColLimits=c(input$colorRng_min, input$colorRng_max)
    }

    distfun_row = function(x) stats::dist(x, method = input$distFun_row)
    distfun_col =  function(x) stats::dist(x, method = input$distFun_col)

    req(input$hclustFun_row)
    hclustfun_row = function(x) stats::hclust(x, method = input$hclustFun_row)
    hclustfun_col = function(x) stats::hclust(x, method = input$hclustFun_col)

    p <- heatmaply::heatmaply(data.in,
                              main = input$main,xlab = input$xlab,ylab = input$ylab,
                              row_text_angle = input$row_text_angle,
                              column_text_angle = input$column_text_angle,
                              dendrogram = input$dendrogram,
                              branches_lwd = input$branches_lwd,
                              seriate = input$seriation,
                              colors=eval(parse(text=paste0(input$pal,'(',input$ncol,')'))),
                              distfun_row =  distfun_row,
                              hclustfun_row = hclustfun_row,
                              distfun_col = distfun_col,
                              hclustfun_col = hclustfun_col,
                              k_col = input$c, 
                              k_row = input$r,
                              limits = ColLimits) %>% 
      plotly::layout(margin = list(l = input$l, b = input$b))

    p$elementId <- NULL

    p

  })

  shiny::observeEvent(data.sel(),{
    output$heatout <- plotly::renderPlotly({
      interactiveHeatmap()
    })
  })

  output$tables=DT::renderDataTable(data.sel(),server = T,filter='top',
                                    extensions = c('Scroller','FixedHeader','FixedColumns','Buttons','ColReorder'),
                                    options = list(
                                      dom = 't',
                                      buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print','colvis'),
                                      colReorder = TRUE,
                                      scrollX = TRUE,
                                      fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                      fixedHeader = TRUE,
                                      deferRender = TRUE,
                                      scrollY = 500,
                                      scroller = TRUE
                                    ))

  #Clone Heatmap ----
  shiny::observeEvent({interactiveHeatmap()},{
    h<-interactiveHeatmap()

    l<-list(main = input$main,xlab = input$xlab,ylab = input$ylab,
            row_text_angle = input$row_text_angle,
            column_text_angle = input$column_text_angle,
            dendrogram = input$dendrogram,
            branches_lwd = input$branches_lwd,
            seriate = input$seriation,
            colors=paste0(input$pal,'(',input$ncol,')'),
            distfun_row =  input$distFun_row,
            hclustfun_row = input$hclustFun_row,
            distfun_col = input$distFun_col,
            hclustfun_col = input$hclustFun_col,
            k_col = input$c, 
            k_row = input$r,
            limits = paste(c(input$colorRng_min, input$colorRng_max),collapse=',')
    )


    l=data.frame(Parameter=names(l),Value=do.call('rbind',l),row.names = NULL,stringsAsFactors = F)
    l[which(l$Value==''),2]='NULL'
    paramTbl=print(xtable::xtable(l),type = 'html',include.rownames=FALSE,print.results = F,html.table.attributes = c('border=0'))


    h$width='100%'
    h$height='800px'
    s<-htmltools::tags$div(style="position: relative; bottom: 5px;",
                           htmltools::HTML(paramTbl),
                           htmltools::tags$em('This heatmap visualization was created using',
                                              htmltools::tags$a(href="https://github.com/yonicd/shinyHeatmaply/",target="_blank",'shinyHeatmaply'),
                                              Sys.time()
                           )
    )

    output$downloadData <- shiny::downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("heatmaply-", gsub(' ','_',Sys.time()), ".html", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        libdir <- paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file)),"_files", sep = "")

        htmltools::save_html(htmltools::browsable(htmltools::tagList(h,s)),file=file,libdir = libdir)
        # if (!htmlwidgets:::pandoc_available()) {
        if (!pandoc_available()) {
          stop("Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. For details see:\n", 
               "https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md")
        }

        # htmlwidgets:::pandoc_self_contained_html(file, file)
        pandoc_self_contained_html(file, file)
        unlink(libdir, recursive = TRUE)
      }
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: The app works fine for me, also with your data (please see the gif).

Comment: Just updated one more time using your variable name `sample_013` to make it clear.

Comment: Thank you to be very helpful

Comment: this does not work for you? `shinyHeatmaply::launch_heatmaply(sample_013,viewerType = 'browserViewer')`?

Comment: Sure, it works fine for me. I just wanted to point out that `runApp()` calls shouldn't be nested in another server function (as done in the question). I'm not familar with `library(shinyHeatmaply)` - your solution of course is way more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

saving to the file `app.R` the following should also work

```r
library(shinyHeatmaply)

sample_013 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                         NANA = c("ABCB1", "ACVR1B", "ACVR2A", "APC", "ARID1A", "ARID1B"),
                         NADriver = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                         NAsnv_t_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                         NAsnv_o_013 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                         NAindel_t_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                         NAindel_o_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                         NADeleted_ot_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                         NADeleted_o_013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))

shinyHeatmaply::launch_heatmaply(sample_013,viewerType = 'browserViewer')
```

the running the folder
`rsconnect::deployApp("/Users/temporal.UOS-12599/Desktop/New folder")`

should pick up that file and run the app.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know what I should write in ui.r and server.r in new folder to deploy the app. I mean for deploying if I am not wrong I will need ui.r and server.r

Comment: `app.R` can be used instead of `server.R` and `ui.R` (single file app).